# Multiple fixture instances

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I have a set of unit tests that makes use of a fixture class to store [shared context](https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context):

```
public class MSAccessFixture : IDisposable {
    // ...
}

public class MSAccess : IClassFixture<MSAccessFixture> {
    public MSAccess(MSAccessFixture fixture) {
        // ...
    }
```

One of the fields of the fixture class can have two different values.

**How can I run the same set of tests in a given test class against either instance of the fixture?**

Comment: make an abstract test class and two derived ones with different ClassFixtures (needs to be made by default ctor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xunit multiple IClassFixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319420/xunit-multiple-iclassfixtures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, at this time it isn't possible to control what the values of a given fixture instance should be from outside the fixture class. Therefore, the only way to do this is to implement a type hierarchy:

```
BaseFixture
    DerivedFixture1
    DerivedFixture2
```

in which each derived fixture has different values.

(This also means a hierarchy of types for the test class, as is noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36319964/111794)).

Like [so](https://github.com/zspitz/StringAsSql/blob/master/StringAsSql.Tests/MSAccess.cs):

```
public class MSAccessFixtureBase {
    public MSAccessFixtureBase(bool sharedConnection) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class MSAccessFixture : MSAccessFixtureBase {
    public MSAccessFixture() : base(false) { }
}
public class MSAccessFixture1Connection : MSAccessFixtureBase {
    public MSAccessFixture1Connection() : base(true) { }
}

public abstract class MSAccessBase {
    private MSAccessFixtureBase fixture;
    public MSAccessBase(MSAccessFixtureBase fixture) {
        this.fixture = fixture;
        // ...
    }
}

public class MSAccess : MSAccessBase, IClassFixture<MSAccessFixture> {
    public MSAccess(MSAccessFixture fixture) : base(fixture) { }
}
public class MSAccess1Connection : MSAccessBase, IClassFixture<MSAccessFixture1Connection> {
    public MSAccess1Connection(MSAccessFixture1Connection fixture) : base(fixture) { }
}
```